# create a control to accept script (javascript) without using third party library

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to create a control (text area , input) to accept script , 
the application i want to integrate is personal and want to avoid using third party libraries for the same.
 Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want it executed client-side?

Not the greatest practice, but without knowing more, the best I can think of is something like this:

```
var result = eval( document.querySelector('#script-control').value );
```